# How do I display a block while on a page which was created by views?

Tags: drupal-7

Status :
I created a page by views module.

name - "Culture and Tradition"
path - "culture-and-tradition"

which to display the "Title" and "Body" of the content by content type.

And I created a block name is "Blk Culture and Tradition" which to display the Title of content by views module.

And then I went to the configuration of structure->block->"Blk Culture and Tradition"
and place the culture-and-tradition into the "Only the listed pages"

Problem : The block "Blk Culture and Tradition" is not display when I went to the views's page of "culture-and-tradition".

How do I display a block while on a page which was created by views

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [here](http://drupal.org/node/531458). And remove marking of content type(s).